# How do I implement a function which prints a vector of any type and length?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a function which takes a vector of any type and any lengths to print it.

This is my implementation right now:

```
fn print_vec<T>(v: &T) {
    for i in v.iter() {
        println("{}",i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = [1,2,3];
    print_vec(vec);
}
```

but I get the following error:

```
mismatched types:
expected '&_'
found '[_; 3]'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Problem 1

```
fn print_vec<T>(v: &T);
```

Your function declaration wants a **reference** to an item, but you are passing in the item (`[1,2,3]`). Let's change your code to pass in a reference:

```
print_vec(&vec);
```

#### Problem 2

You are calling `println`, but the macro is called `println!`.

#### Problem 3

```
error: type `&T` does not implement any method in scope named `iter`
```

You have a reference to *any type*, and not all types implement the method `iter`! For example, what would `5.iter()` mean? Or `true.iter()`? So, let's change it to a type that does have that method — a *slice*:

```
fn print_vec<T>(v: &[T])
```

#### Problem 4

```
error: the trait `core::fmt::Display` is not implemented for the type `T`
```

We have said that we want a slice, but the items in the slice can be *any type*, and not all types are printable! We can use a *trait bound* to restrict the type of `T` to only things that can be printed using the `{}` formatter:

```
fn print_vec<T>(v: &[T])
    where T: std::fmt::Display
```

#### All together

```
fn print_vec<T>(v: &[T])
    where T: std::fmt::Display
{
    for i in v.iter() {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let vec = [1, 2, 3];
    print_vec(&vec);
}
```

#### Extra note

```
let vec = [1, 2, 3];
```

You should **not** call this variable `vec`, because it *is not a `Vec`*. In fact, it is an *array*. In Rust, arrays, `Vec`s, and slices are all distinct concepts — I'm sure there are other questions detailing the differences.

For similar reasons, you shouldn't call the method `print_vec`, as it accepts a slice now.